# Perfect Halver Construction?

Tags: sorting, circuits

A sorting network is a circuit-based approach to sorting, built out of CompareExchange gates, which compute the function:
$$\mathsf{CompareExchange}(x,y) = (\min(x,y), \max(x,y))$$
The input to the circuit can be assumed to be in $\{0,1\}^n$ (which is viewed as $n$ separate wires).
As sorting networks are phrased in terms of circuits, their control flow can only be a function of $n$, and many $O(n\log n)$ sorts cannot be phrased in terms of sorting networks naively.

A *perfect halver* is a weakening of the notion of a sorting network. It is another circuit made out of CompareExchange gates, but it does not "fully sort" its input. Instead, it separates the input into a "high set" $H$ and a "low set" $L$, such that all $\ell\in L$ are less than or equal to all $h\in H$, and $|H| = |L| = n/2$.

Given a perfect halver of depth $f(n)$ one can construct a sorting network in depth $O(f(n)\log n)$ via a simple recursion. Since there is a lower bound $\Omega(\log n)$ on the depth of perfect halvers (see for example the introduction of [this](https://users.encs.concordia.ca/~chvatal/notes/aks.pdf)), this gives a bound $\Omega((\log n)^2)$ on the depth of any such construction, which corresponds roughly to a $\Omega(n (\log n)^2)$ sorting algorithm.
This is usually stated to motivate the construction of $\epsilon$-halvers, which are $O(1)$ depth and the main technique behind the AKS sorting network, which achieves $O(\log n)$ depth.

I have an application where a perfect halver would be desirable, even if it's $O(\log n)$ depth (assuming it has good constants). I'm having difficulty finding any constructions of perfect halvers though, as all of my searches seem to lead to AKS-related constructions.

Are there any constructions of perfect halvers with $O(\log n)$ depth in the literature? I'm interested in practical constructions, so answers like "Use AKS", while technically $O(\log n)$ depth, are uninteresting to me.

The motivation is sorting in a particular situation where all elements in the array $A$ occur with the same frequency, so a $O(\log n)$ depth perfect halver directly leads to an $O(n\log n)$ sorting algorithm on these restricted problem instances (which are of independent interest to me).

Comment: In "all $l \in L$ are less than all $h \in H$, and $|H|=|L|=n/2$", do you mean "less than *or equal to*"? Otherwise there is no possible solution for an input consisting of $2n$ binary digits, unless exactly $n$ of them are 0s and exactly $n$ are 1s.

Comment: Yes, I meant less than or equal to (although in my particular application it's known that the # of zeros = # of ones = $n$)

Comment: If you really always have the # of zeros = # of ones then you don't need any logic gates at all -- just set the first $n$ outputs to the constant 0, and the second $n$ outputs to the constant 1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The sorting network will be applied to items of the form $(b, D)$, where $b\in\{0,1\}$, and $D$ is associated data. I want it to sort things according to $b$, but permute the $D$'s as well. This rules out solutions such as that.

Comment: I see. Please add that to the question :)